# Глюк Ripple Effect в TabLayout с FloatingActionButton

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Имеется две вкладки, реализованные через `TabLayout`, `ViewPager` и `Fragment`. При отображении первой вкладки показывается кнопка `FloatingActionButton`. При переходе на вторую вкладку эта кнопка плавно скрывается.

Если тапать по заголовку первой вкладки, то наблюдается `Ripple Effect`. Однако, если тапнуть по заголовку второй вкладки, то этот эффект начинает отображаться, но не успевает закончиться. Он резко пропадает именно в момент когда полностью исчезает кнопка `FAB`.

Иногда при возврате на первую вкладку по тапу, этот эффект вовсе отсутствует. Это происходит от случая к случаю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему? Возможно что-то с чем-то конфликтует?

```
...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.my_container);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.my_fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
                {
                ...
                }
            });

        // плавно убирает кнопку fab
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
            {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
                {
                switch (position)
                    {
                    case 0: fab.show(); break;
                    case 1: fab.hide(); break;
                    }
                }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
            });
        }

    private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
        {
        private SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager)
            {
            super(fragmentManager);
            }

        // отображение определённого фрагмента
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
            {
            switch (position)
                {
                case 0: return new Fragment1(); // отображаем содержимое фрагмента 1
                case 1: return new Fragment2(); // отображаем содержимое фрагмента 2
                default: return null;
                }
            }

        // общее количество вкладок
        @Override
        public int getCount()
            {
            return 2;
            }

        // заголовки вкладок
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
            {
            switch (position)
                {
                case 0: return "ВКЛАДКА 1";
                case 1: return "ВКЛАДКА 2";
                }
            return null;
            }
        }
    }
```